# Formatting rule to change other cells based on cell value

Tags: ag-grid

I'm trying in Aggrid to do the following formatting:

- if cell X has some value, then change the formatting of cells Y an Z (different columns, same row)

Is this possible to do ? Which functions from the API should I use ?

edit : alternatively, because my grid data won't be edited, I can also look for a way to simply define ahead of time of cells so they get displayed with a specific style, while other cells of the same column on different rows get displayed with another style (eg different font color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems quite straightforward what you're trying to achieve. You need to use the `cellClassRules` property for your Y and Z columns, and format them appropriately, depending on the value of column X.

Here is a simple example which set the background colour of columns Y and Z to the colour specified in column X:

```
cellClassRules: {
  'rag-red': (params) => {
    return params.data.x == 'red';
  },
  'rag-amber': (params) => {
    return params.data.x == 'amber';
  },
  'rag-green': (params) => {
    return params.data.x == 'green';
  },
},
```

And the definition of the css classes:

```
  .rag-red {
    background-color: lightcoral;
  }
  .rag-green {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
  .rag-amber {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
  }
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mWBoVX9bVTd0KoJa).